Cloud Firestore - The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff
I am trying to connect my Flutter project to Firestore, but this error occurred while trying to read and write data: [cloud_firestore] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff. I am currently based in China. But I am using a VPN, and the authentication function works.
In my code, I am just trying to perform a simple read data command for testing.
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final docRef = db.collection("1").doc("1");
docRef.get().then(
     (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
          final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          // ...
        },
        onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
);

Here is what I have done to integrate Firestore:

Created Firebase Project and added Google-Info.plist to the project
Initialized Firebase with await Firebase.initializeApp( options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, );
Run the command multiple times with pub clean and pub get

Is it a Internet issue, my issue with the integration, or Firebase issue? Thank you.
